CodeIgniter 4 Validation Rules not working
I want to ask about validation rules using CodeIgniter 4. The Validation not sending the wrong message.
Here's my Controller to execute the form
         if (!$this->validate([
            'name'  => [
                'rules'      => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[25]',
                'errors'     => [
                    'required'      => 'Name actress must be filled.',
                    'min_length'    => 'Name actress minimum 3 character.',
                    'max_length'    => 'Name actress maximum 25 character.',
                ]
            ],
            'years' => [
                'rules'  => 'required|min_length[4]|max_length[4]|is_natural',
                'errors' => [
                    'required'      => 'Years must be filled.',
                    'min_length'    => 'Years minimum 4 numbers.',
                    'max_length'    => 'Years maximum 4 numbers.',
                    'is_natural'    => 'Years only numbers.',
                ]
            ],
        ])) {
        $validation = $this->validation;
        session()->setFlashdata('wrong', 'there is an error, check your form again.');
        return redirect()->to('/home/actress')->withInput()->with('validation', $validation);

Here's my Home Controller
    public function actress(): string
    {
        $data = [
            'nationalities' => $this->NationalityModel->findAll(),
            'validation' => $this->validation
        ];
        return view('index/actress', $data);
    }

And here's the view form
<form action="/add/actress" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <?= csrf_field(); ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control <?= ($validation->hasError('name')) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" name="name" id="name" autocomplete="off" value="<?= old('name'); ?>">
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        <?= $validation->getError('name'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="years">Years</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control <?= ($validation->hasError('years')) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" name="years" id="years" autocomplete="off" value="<?= old('years'); ?>">
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        <?= $validation->getError('years'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nationality">Nationality</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="nationality" id="nationality">
                        <option value="">Choose Nationality...</option>
                        <?php foreach($nationalities as $nationality) : ?>
                            <option value="<?= $nationality['code_nationality']; ?>"><?= $nationality['nationality']; ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1" name="favorite" id="favorite">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="favorite">
                        Favorite Actress
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>

Nothings problem if I fill the form with Correct value. But if I fill the form with wrong value, the validation not sending the errors value.

What is $this->validation?
